# Runtime error when using DataObject.PutInClipboard Method

Tags: vba, clipboard

I have a macro that runs in my PC. When someone else runs it, it throws the following exception:

```
"Run-time error '-2147221036 (800401d4)'
DataObject:PutInClipboard CloseClipboard Failed"
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim buf As String, FSO As Object
Dim CB As New DataObject

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With FSO.OpenTextFile(sFile, 1)
    buf = .ReadAll
    buf = Replace(buf, ",", Chr(9))
    .Close
End With

With CB
    .SetText buf
    .PutInClipboard   // Here cause the exception.
End With
```

Comment: Your code works for me. As expected I suppose. I've encountered a similar error when I was using an API call to access the clipboard and then tried to use the `PutInClipboard` method.

Comment: @mkingston thank you.  It's really hard to catch the trouble!

Comment: Yeah I can believe it. Good luck, sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I don't know what causes it; my guess is that if your PC's resources are taxed, the Clipboard may not perform as quickly as you would like.  My solution was to put the code in a loop and break when it works.

```
Dim buf As String, FSO As Object
Dim CB As New DataObject
dim errnum as long
dim errdesc as string
dim i as long

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With FSO.OpenTextFile(sFile, 1)
    buf = .ReadAll
    buf = Replace(buf, ",", Chr(9))
    .Close
End With

With CB
    .SetText buf

    On Error Resume Next
        For i=1 to 200
            .PutInClipboard
            errnum = Err.Number
            errdesc = Err.Description
            If errnum = 0 Then Exit For
        Next i
    On Error Goto 0

    If errnum > 0 Then
        ' Do something to handle an epic failure... didn't work even after
        ' 200 tries.
        Err.Raise errnum, errdesc
    End If

End With
```

I had to do the same thing with `Worksheet.PasteSpecial`.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error in Windows 10 (64 bit), Word 2003. The error has disappeared when I have used:

```
.Clear
```

i.e. have cleared the DataObject, immediately before:

```
.SetText
```

Edit: Works also in Windows 10 (32 bit), Word 2013

Comment: this made it worse for me, now I see the error almost every time. Windows 10 64bit, Excel 2016 64bit